# Leveraged positions with interest rate swaps

Tags: interest-rate, leverage

Why is a position in an interest swap a leveraged position (for instance when considering a plain vanilla swap, i.e. fixed for floating swap)?

Comment: how is this helping you with personal finance? it an economic and accounting question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the proper forum for this question

Comment: Because marginal instruments are typical hedgers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an interest-rate swap, you are getting exposure to fixed-income cash flows that are based on notional amounts that you don't typically own.

For example, if you are on the paying end of a fixed rate of 4% on $100MM notional, you don't need to have $100MM in capital (or own $100MM worth of bonds!). You only need sufficient capital to satisfy the margin requirements of the dealer / clearer... which will be considerably less than $100MM. Hence the "synthetic" nature of swaps and the leverage built in to the product.